# Comparing two branches with eclipse git shows nonexistent conflicts

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am using Eclipse git to compare two branches, but it shows nonexistent conflicts for a lot of files :

[image]

What can I do to make Egit compare show actual conflicts ?

Comment: what did you do to get the screen, and please can you attach a higher resolution screen shot as its difficult to read?